# Why is PyInstaller removing the transparency from my icon?

Tags: python-2.7, icons, pyinstaller

I freeze my program using the following command:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe pyinstaller.py --onefile --windowed --icon=logo.ico program.py
```

The icon I created has a transparent background, but after freezing the icon has a solid white background. What is happening?

Edit to add: This is the icon. (It's a PNG instead of an ICO because stack won't let me upload an ICO?)

[image]

Comment: can you show the icon?

Comment: Added. I exported it into a PNG because stackoverflow wouldn't take an ICO, but you get the idea.